# timestamping history file causing erroneous lines in history command

Tags: bash, environment-variables, perl

I have .bash_profile setup to export to a history file:

```
export HISTFILE=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
```

Then I am exporting time stamps for the history command.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y/%m/%d %T "
```

This combination caused epoch time stamps to be written to the history file:

```
#1463962023
top
```

So I wrote in a perl one liner into the .bash_profile to only write in the human readable time stamp into the file thus eliminating the epoch line: ( and a few other lines)

```
format_history () {
local file=/root/history/.bash_hist-$(who -m | awk '{print $1}')
perl -i -pe 's/^#(\d{10})$/"# ".localtime($1)/e' "$file"
}

shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

So now my exported file looks like this:

```
# Sun May 22 19:06:41 2016
last
```

Which is great and exactly what I want. However, this has the unwanted side effect of appending a dedicated line in the history command which contains nothing but dates that does not need to be there.

```
 824  2016/05/22 19:07:33 # Sun May 22 19:06:41 2016
 825  2016/05/22 19:07:33 last
```

How can I write to the file like I want without causing the history command to report these unwanted lines?

NOTE - This anomoly with the history command seems to be "activated" when I log in to a system. ( I use ssh) I can be in session, run 10 commands, then run the history command and all looks normal. However as soon as a log out and log back in and run the history command, it will display the erroneous lines.

UPDATE: I have narrowed down the problem to the line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;format_history;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

When I comment out this line the history command works as expected. However, this was also the command that ran the formatting on the history file. I have tried to remove the "history -a" part from the line, leaving the rest, but that does not make any difference. If I were to leave the whole line commented out, how could I invoke the formatting on the file using the perl script?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the history file alone and implement your recording of commands in the prompt_command handler instead. I would also make it write to a private log file then you don't have the conflicts with other usages of the history file or issues with other users accessing /root

Comment: The history file will contain comments on the end of lines , try it , its handy for documenting what you think a command should be doing. You can also search them with Ctrl r